# CodeIgniter base_url() failure

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

My base url function is not working in the latest version of code igniter. Trying to use it in a style sheet path, and then just echoed it on a view to see if it worked there, to no avail.

calling it this way:

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

and then with the style sheet like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
```

And here it is assigned in my config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.codeigniter.dev/';
$config['server_root'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as [guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

is the library loaded?

Comment: oh duh, good point. which page should I load it on? the controller for the view I'm trying to use it on, or is there a more universal spot?

Comment: you can load it in the controller (when it's needed) or use the autoload http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Comment: just for future reference. I had this in my autoload.php $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); would that not do it?

Comment: ok - that makes sense but it's still not working. That is what I've had in it all along :(

Comment: I figured it out. I had to combine the form helper within the url helper and it worked. thanks

Comment: @LightningWrist: `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');`